# Floating label on input focus

Tags: styled-components

I am trying to implement floating label on input focus as this one with styled-components:

> https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/299/

I have made this: https://codesandbox.io/s/92474z2wvw

I think the problem is this syntax:

```
&:not(:focus):valid ~ ${Label} {
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
```

What is the proper syntax for this in styled-components?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this floating label component [react-styled-floating-label](https://github.com/ihor/react-styled-floating-label). It can be styled with styled-components.

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here I suppose. The label will always apply one of the styles since your input is always "valid when not focused.

The second problem is that it's easier to make the label change according to the input, than it is to let the input affect the label.

So you had this piece of code here:

```
const Input = styled.input`
  &:focus ~ ${Label}, &:not(:focus):valid ~ ${Label} {
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
`;
```

And instead it may be easier to do the following:

```
const Label = styled.label`
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 14px;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;

  ${Input}:focus ~ & {
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
`;
```

I've modified your code sandbox to reflect this, and when removing the second rule it starts to work. Have a look at this, it might explain what ":valid" implies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid

And here's my link to the forked sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pp7x5xylo7